# set a checkbox to true if all the checkbox in the order Lines are true

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

on the new Sales Orders page, I added a checkbox to be true if the (unit price > cost) in the order Lines table

[image]

the problem is I need to find out  if all the checkboxes in the order Lines table  are true then set a checkbox outside the table to be true but I can't find out how

[image]

[image]

in x_studio_check_min_cost compute when I add this

```
for record in self:
  for one_check in record.invoice_ids.invoice_line_ids.sale_line_ids.x_studio_min_price_sale_by_cost:
    if one_check == True:
      record[('x_studio_check_min_cost')] = True
    else:
      record[('x_studio_check_min_cost')] = False
```

in the sales order, this error appears

```
 File "", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: <class 'TypeError'>: "'bool' object is not iterable" while evaluating
"for record in self:\n  for one_check in record.invoice_ids.invoice_line_ids.sale_line_ids.x_studio_min_price_sale_by_cost:\n    if one_check == True:\n      record[('x_studio_check_min_cost')] = True\n    else:\n      record[('x_studio_check_min_cost')] = False\n"
```

I am using odoo studio as I am new to odoo and have no experience creating modules

thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this code ,hope it will help.

```
  for record in self:
    flag = False
    if any(line.x_studio_min_price_sale_by_cost for line in record.order_line):
        flag = True
    if not flag:
        record['x_studio_check_min_cost'] = True
```

In the compute option of the field `x_studio_check_min_cost`, 
you can see the **Advanced Properties** head, right ? Below that in the **Dependencies** field set the field name as order_line , in the **Compute** field copy paste the above code (Beware of the Indentation).

Comment: Hi Ajmal, I added more info to the question. Also, where can I add this code (odoo.sh)

Comment: Hi Moaz , i made some changes in the answer , check it and update.

Comment: `x_studio_check_min_cost` by default is `True` when I load the page with is not a problem but if one line is `True` checks out the other lines is ignored

Comment: i need all the Min Price Sale By Cost to be `False` in order for the Check Min Cost to. be  `True`

Comment: means if Min Price Sale By Cost in all lines is False , then the field Check Min Cost  , become True , is that you need ?

Comment: it works now thank you. can you point me to any online course or resource to help me learn more about odoo development? also, I opened a question on odoo if you want the karma point https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/set-a-checkbox-to-true-if-all-the-checkbox-in-the-order-lines-are-true-150716

Comment: can u plz explain why the Dependencies is only `order_line`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194694/discussion-between-moaz-mabrok-and-ajmal).

Comment: Hey guys, the answer doesn't fit the question at all -> it has an `any()` in it while the subject of the question states "set a checkbox to true if all the checkbox in the order Lines are true". Please change the question.